# Does the equality $ \dfrac{10!}{6!} = 7! $ hold any special (geometric) meaning?

Tags: combinatorics, intuition, factorial, visualization

I've come across the following simple, but unexpected equality numerous times accidentally.

$$ \frac{10!}{6!} = 7! $$

which is the same as

$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7 = 7*8*9*10$$

Does it hold any specific (geometric?) meaning? I've graphed out numerous similar identities, but didn't find any that have an unexpected result similar to the above (leaving aside the trivial $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} = n$).

Comment: thought to be the last example except for the infinite family $(n!)! = (n! - 1)! \cdot n!$

Comment: Possibly [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3916909/248217).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some explanation as to why the two factorial expressions are equal, just break each expression down into prime factors.
$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7=7*8*9*10$$

$$1*2*3*(2^2)*5*(2*3)*7=7*(2^3)*(3^2)*(2*5)$$

$$1*2^4*3^2*5*7=1*2^4*3^2*5*7$$

I know this only scratches at the surface of your questions about it, but I hope you still find it of some value.