# Is the fact that $6!7!=10!$ a pure numerical coincidence?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, factorial

I was reading about factorials recently, and I happened to come across the curious, almost pseudo-Pythagorean-seeming fact that $$6!7!=10!$$ I was greatly intrigued by this, but couldn't think of any justification other than "it just happens to be that way".

Yes, I have seen [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112709/664819). I understand that it's not exactly known when or where these crop up in general, and in fact only a few are generally known. I'm just asking about whether, for this particular case, there is a reason why this fact "should" be the case beyond just the relatively prosaic fact that $6!=8\times 9\times 10$, the missing factors from $7!$.

So my question is: Is it a fact that seems coincidental but actually has a very good rationale, like that $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx 262537412640768743.999999999999\approx 262537412640768744$, which has to do with Heegner numbers and a bunch of other things I don't quite understand? Or is it a pure coincidence like the fact that $e^{\pi}-\pi\approx 19.999099979\approx 20$?

Comment: This came up recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903361/6-cdot-7-10-is-there-a-natural-bijection-between-s-6-times-s-7-and-s-1

Comment: Do you want more? Consider Fibonacci sequence $$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,\ldots$$ Well, $144$ is the **only** perfect square in the infinite sequence

Comment: Incidentally, $10!$ seconds is exactly $6$ weeks.

Comment: @Favst Fascinating! I'm not generally familiar with group theory, but that is just delightful.

Comment: @Joe That is interesting- I suppose I should have spotted that. But that really is just a coincidence, coming from the particular way in which humans split up our time periods.

Comment: @Raffaele did you know 2 is the only even prime in fibonacci sequence? haha (this joke of course sucks since 2 is the only even prime soooo.....) Edit: wait what about the 3-4-5 right triangle in the linked post in re the OP's saying about 'pseudo-Pythagorean-seeming' ? (so i guess your joke sucks too?)

Comment: @Raffaele 1 is also a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

> almost pseudo-Pythagorean-seeming

Check out the ff answer in one of the linked posts

[$6!\cdot 7!=10!$. Is there a natural bijection between $S_6\times S_7$ and $S_{10}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903361/6-cdot-7-10-is-there-a-natural-bijection-between-s-6-times-s-7-and-s-1/3916909#3916909)

The answer begins with

> It may be connected with, of all things, the 3−4−5 right triangle!